# Project installed on local showing nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... even after the installation of all the packages

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node API Project installed on my local system shows **nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...** even after installing all the packages. The same project was working earlier, and is working on another PC but not on mine. Not able to understand which file have exactly the error

```
(node:8728) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

> project@1.0.0 start
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
D:\Works\project\api\v1\modules\user\validation\schema\schema.js:4
    Signup = Joi.object({
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: As far as I can see however, your error is in D:\Works\project\api\v1\modules\user\validation\schema\schema.js, line 4. I think you might want to check your code whether it is valid or not. That looks like a Syntax Error IMHO

Comment: @RishiMath I have checked the same but there is no code syntax issue as If I am commenting the whole file's code then the error starts showing for another file.

Comment: That's probably because the code which you are commenting out is depended upon by other files